# dns redirect include path into query

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, redirect

I have a following DNS setup:

```
www.example.com    CNAME   xyz.elasticbeanstack.com
exaple.com         A       redirect(301) http://www.example.com
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

However, the path of the request is not passed to www-like enpdoint.

For example,

`exaple.com/abc` is redireced to `www.example.com` rather than `www.example.com/abc`

How do I keep the path while redirecting, or maybe there is another way to make `example.com/abc` links work along with `www.example.com/abc`?

Comment: Some basic formatting.

Comment: @m213prog i suggest you to contact support on AWS